# Add image type attribute for category

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

In Magento 2, How we can create custom attribute for image upload for category.
I tried it using the install script and followed the core magento code for creating category attribute, It add an attribute but does not save the image for the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Magento version 2.1.5.